# layout is not showing when broadcast receiver is sending message

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

I have a dashboard activity which have 3 fragment ,initially it is calling a home fragment, I want to show a layout when my I receive a broadcast of Internet is not connected but my layout is always showing null pointer exception...at first the visibility of  internet layout is gone.

when I set my visibility on then it is showing and overlapping my fragment design but as soon as set its visibility gone and then want to show it always show error

why this happening

checkNet.java

```
 DashBoardActivity dashBoardActivity = new DashBoardActivity();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            if (isOnline(context)) {
               dashBoardActivity.checkNet(true);
                Log.e("checkInternet", "App is back to Online  ");

            } else {

                dashBoardActivity.checkNet(false);
                Log.e("checkInternet", "Conectivity Failure  !!! ");
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private boolean isOnline(Context context) {

        try {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            
            return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

this function is in dashboard acitvity

```
   public  void checkNet(boolean value) {

        if (value) {
            Log.e("Connected", "Yes ");
             
        }
        else {
            Log.e("Connected", "NO ");
            something_wrong_LL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           
}
```

dashboard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="DashBoardActivity">





            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/something_wrong_LL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/card1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito"
                    android:text="somethingWrong"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray_2"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/retry_BT"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:text="RETRY"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_background_bg"
                    android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"/>

            </LinearLayout>






    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/card1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/card1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:contentPadding="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"
        app:cardElevation="16dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">



       .
       .
       .
       .
       .
       .
       .
        
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share the null pointer exception stack trace? Also, the layout you provided is malformed as it contains dots.

Comment: `W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference ` .............@tomerpacific this is the error and the dots are the bottom navigation ..if you want i can upload that also

Comment: Where in the code does this exception originate from? Please add the code.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals#ActivatingComponents

Both BroadcastReceiver and Activity are Application Components
therefore, it is desirable to activate them as `Intent`.

The Activity is called from the `onReceive()` inside to the `startActivity()`

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, TestActivity.class);
            boolean isOnlineState = isOnline(context);
            
            // to execute checkNet()
            intent.putExtra("checkInternet", isOnlineState);

            if (isOnlineState) {
                Log.e("checkInternet", "App is back to Online  ");
            } else {
                Log.e("checkInternet", "Conectivity Failure  !!! ");
            }

            context.startActivity(activityIntent);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you elaborate more

Comment: added code snippet, you can add intent extra to use checknet() parameter